# How to remove word if appears more than once

Tags: c#

I have some string that I got from server, and sometimes it could get string with duplicate words, like:

"this is example of is example string"

but sometimes I get only:

"this is example of string"

I know that only "is example" can be duplicate, so, is there any shortcut where I don't need to find index of that string and than count if there is more than one?

Comment: Search for regex pattern `(\bis example .*)\bis example\b` and replace the matching substring with the captured text.

Comment: I would say you should try to find the root cause of the bug. Trying to "correct" bad input data is fraught with danger.

Comment: Bad input data is not from my server, it's from server that I don't have access

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq

```
string nonRepeated = string.Join(' ', "my string string".Split(' ').Distinct());
```

Comment: Hmmm it could affect rest of string where I can have duplicate words, I need only that exactly sentence to remove if more than once

Comment: This will remove "if only more than once" and keep the order, like the first "is example" will be kept but the latter one won't.

Comment: The OP wants to remove `is example` if repeated. Not `string`, even if repeated.